# Detect route/view transition in Ember.js application

Tags: ember.js

The router of my application looks like this (it's CoffeeScript):

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'conversations', { path: '/' } ->
    @resource 'conversation', { path: ':conversation_id' }
    @route 'new'
```

So, in my app, I have paths like `/new`, `/1`, `/2`, etc.

I would like to detect a transition from `/1` to `/2` to make some initializations in my view (basically, put the focus on a textarea field). Unfortunately, as `/1` and `/2` use the same route, it seems nearly impossible to detect that transition.

I tried by using `didInsertElement` in the view (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929672/emberjs-didinsertelement-for-previously-displayed-view)) or by observing `currentPath` in the controller (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425276/detect-route-transitions-in-emberjs-1-0-0-pre-4)). It works fine if I go from `/new` to `/1` (different routes) but not if I go from `/1` to `/2`.

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesarosen/1592144) suggesting to use the `StateManager` but it seems outdated (and I'm not sure it's really what I need).

What do you suggest me to do?

**EDIT**

It seems that `setupController` is called every time so I decided to overload it like this:

```
App.ConversationRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'model', model
    # do something here?

}
```

And I want the `init` method in my view to be called:

```
App.ConversationView = Ember.View.extend {

  init: ->
    @$('form textarea').focus()

}
```

But I still can't figure out how to make these two things work together (it's a problem because I read that the controller is not supposed to know about the view).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `didInsertElement` view hook and an observer.

```
App.ConversationView = Ember.View.extend

  didInsertElement: ->
    @focusOnTextarea()

  modelChanged: (->
    @focusOnTextarea()
  ).observes('controller.model')

  focusOnTextarea: ->
    @$('form textarea').focus()
```

In the case of going from /1 to /2, the route and view are not changing. Ember does the least amount of work possible. There's no need to re-render the view, so it doesn't. But this tripped me up too, and I think it's a big gotcha.

Also, if you override `init` in your view, make sure to call `@_super()`.

Note: the `model` hook is only called when landing on a page to deserialize the URL, not when transitioning from another page and changing the model instance.

Answer (score 1):

`Route#model` is your friend here. It will receive a `params` hash containing information from the URL on every route change (even when changing just which instance of a class is being viewed) In your case,

```
App.ConversationRoute = Ember.Route.extend {
  model: (params) ->
    App.Conversation.find params.conversation_id
  setupController: (controller, conversation) ->
    // you have the correct Conversation object
```

The [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) have more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The `didInsertElement` method of the view is the best method if you need to instantiate something on your view. If you need to have the controller do something when the template loads, you can put the call in the `setupController` method of your route:

```
App.FirstRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller){
        controller.onload();
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/Q5Kbz/

This will be called each time that route is loaded. Try the jsfidle. Click along to the second template and then use your browser's back button. The onload should fire again.

Also, **fun fact**, you can use the `deactivate` method as an unload, to do anything you need to that controller when the user navigates away from that route:

```
App.FirstRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  deactivate: function(){
    this.controller.unload();
  }
});
```

#### Unrelated

One thing to note, (not directly related to your question) if you set the model on the controller in the `setupController` method, it will overwrite your controllers `content` property each time that route is loaded. To prevent this, put a conditional around the assignment:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.onload();
  if (model && (!controller.content || Ember.keys(controller.content).length === 0)) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope. setupController not called everytime if you are changing params on a child route.  Neither will didInsertElement